# Set Fragments with TabLayout and Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablayout

My project has a NavigationDrawer and a TabLayout. I'm just looking for setting a specific fragment in a specific menu in a specific tab.

I mean, almost each menu item has 3 differents tabs (not specially the same) and I want to set a fragment who will be different in each tab for each menu item.

The 3 tabs are the same in each menu item.

What I have to do ? I though of about setContentView() but I cannot make it work properly.

Here is screenshots of my app:

[Navigation Drawer with all menu items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kYxH.png)

[Sliding Tabs of a menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDP20.png)

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            MainActivity.this));

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    findViewById(R.id.viewpager).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs).setVisibility(View.GONE);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Pourquoi tu touches à ce bouton ?", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    /*
        Début Drawer Menu
    */
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    /*
        Fin Drawer Menu
    */
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.content_main) {
        findViewById(R.id.viewpager).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_equations) {
        findViewById(R.id.viewpager).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_lois) {
        findViewById(R.id.viewpager).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_stats) {
        findViewById(R.id.viewpager).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tests) {
        findViewById(R.id.viewpager).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_partager) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_parametres) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.slabre.mathix/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.slabre.mathix/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
} }
```

This is the SampleFragmentPagerAdapter.java, used to manage the fragments but only on each tabs :

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Calcul", "Résultat", "Infos" };
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

And so the PageFragment.java :

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment{
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Finally this is the app_bar_main.xml included by the activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.slabre.mathix.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I really don't know if you need more files, just ask me if you want more.

Comment: Each NavigationView item needs to essentially replace the `content_main.xml` in the Activity. Toggling the visibility of the ViewPager isn't doing that

Comment: Oh, ok, but what do you man about replacing ?And so, in which way I have to do that ?

Comment: It's quite a complex process to completely answer here, but are you using individual Fragments for each menu item? Or do you just have a set of 3 Fragments you want to show in the ViewPager and Tabs that correspond to the menu items?

Comment: I want to use a fragment for each tab from each menu item. DO you understand ? For example, in the menu item A, I have 3 fragments (1 for each tab). In the menu item B, I have 3 others fragments (not the same, but always 1 for each tab).

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but the code in the question always has 3 tabs and Fragments as far as I can tell. You just need to write a lot more classes and hook them all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to implement `getItem(int position)` in the ViewPager adapter to return different Fragments for each of the possible positions in the adapter. Currently it only returns 1 type of Fragment, but passes in the position as an argument, so all menu items show "Fragment #X".

The first step you can do is create different Fragment classes with different layouts and return those in the `getItem` method.

For example, copy the entire class of `PageFragment` and create a `PageTwoFragment` class. Then in the PagerAdapter class, you can do something like

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT; // TODO: Change how many pages 
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 1) { 
        return new PageTwoFragment(); // TODO: Implement 
    } else { 
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
    // TODO: Return other Fragments for other positions 
}
```

The next step would be to create new ViewPager Adapter classes for each of the menu items in the NavigationView and reset the adapter of the ViewPager within the `onNavigationItemSelected` method like so

```
if (id == R.id.nav_equations) {
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    // TODO: Implement EquationsFragmentPagerAdapter 
    viewPager.setAdapter(new EquationsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this));

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Note: You would have less duplicate code if you made field variables for the ViewPager and TabLayout

That should get you different numbers of tabs and various Fragments to swipe through for each menu item.

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand for me. Can you, please, edit your post with more details ? It'll be very nice.

Comment: @Slabre Done. I can't provide exact code because I don't know exactly what you want to show

Comment: This is really helpful ! It doesn't work yet, but almost, I think.

Comment: My app crashes when I select a menu item (e.g. Equations) because I made the change. With the debug mode, I see that it crashes on the viewpager.setAdapter line on the OnNavigationItemsSelected method. Any idea ? I'm looking for

Comment: That would really depend on what the error is. NullPointerException would mean something isn't initialized. That's just one of the many possible errors, though

Comment: I've marked your question as a right solution because your solution worked for me but I had some oversights in my code (like no FragmentTransaction) to correct before, see? Then thank you for your time as well!